# Python user specified help option '-help' and one argument group required then '-help' does not work

Tags: python-3.x

I need to have '-help' option to show help and one argument group with required=True.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -tt
import sys
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='help of sample.py', add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('-help', action="store_true", help="Show this help and exit")

    parser.add_argument('-check', action="store_true", help="Enable check mode")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-sort', action="store_true", help="Do sort")
    group.add_argument('-path', help="Check path")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.help:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(0)

# Standard boilerplate to call the main() function to begin
# the program.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Logs: "help.py -help" does not show the complete help. It says one of argument '-sort/-path' is required. "help.py -help -sort" works fine.

```
$ help.py -help 
usage: help.py [-help] [-check] (-sort | -path PATH)
help.py: error: one of the arguments -sort -path is required
$ help.py -help -sort
usage: help.py [-help] [-check] (-sort | -path PATH)

help of sample.py

optional arguments:
  -help       Show this help and exit
  -check      Enable check mode
  -sort       Do sort
  -path PATH  Check path
$
```

How to make "help.py -help" work and keeping the required=True for the group ?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: This can be solved by changing sys.argv before using argparse module. e.g. Change -he/-hel/-help to -h in sys.argv

```
def change_help_options():
    """ Change -he/-hel/-help to -h in sys.argv """ 
    options = dict()
    options["-h"] = ["-he", "-hel", "-help"]

    for opt, values in options.items():
        for v in values:
            try:
                i = sys.argv.index(v)
                sys.argv[i] = opt
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return

def main():
    change_help_options()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='help of sample.py')
    parser.add_argument('-check', action="store_true", help="Enable check mode")
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-sort', action="store_true", help="Do sort")
    group.add_argument('-path', help="Check path")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```